# Integrating bootstrap in Angular 2 cli project

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-routing

Facing Issues in integrating Bootstrap with angular 2 cli.
I am new to angular 2 CLI please guide me and correct me if I am doing my steps wrong. Thanks in advance.

Steps followed:
 1. npm install bootstrap@next --save
 2. modified .angular-cli.json file
This is what I modified:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
```

restarted the app with ng serve

Errors occured as follows:

> ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js
>   script-loader!./~/tether/dist/tether.js
>   script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve
>   '/Users/sagarbhanushali/projectangularcliyoutube/myProject/node_modules/tether/dist/tether.js'
>   in
>   '/Users/sagarbhanushali/projectangularcliyoutube/myProject/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
>   @ multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js
>   script-loader!./~/tether/dist/tether.js
>   script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

I am new to angular 2 CLI please guide me and correct me if I am doing my steps wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post you package.json file?  I looks like you've got an issue with tether.js, not bootstrap.

Comment: yeah all the packages were not loading together initially and hence used bootstrap-loader and issue is resolved. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved...
used bootstrap loader to solve it. 
run following commands.
1. npm install --save resolve-url-loader --dev
2. npm i --save-dev bootstrap@next bootstrap-loader tether jquery

Comment: Thanks for the answer first of all.  Do you have a canonical reference, or any sources that led you to this answer?  Or just banged around until it worked?  Also, `--dev` is deprecated.  I would recommend following `npm's` suggestion, `npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.` to keep your answer more relevant for a longer period of time.